# Samsung Galaxy SIII and ACR122U Interaction

Tags: android, windows, nfc

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII (version 4.0.4) and a ACR122U-A2 (driver version 1.1.6.3) Contactless Reader. I am trying to get some or other unique code / ID from the phone by making use of the reader.

I can get a unique ID from old school NFC Nokia phones as well as MiFare cards. But as soon as I place the SGS III onto the reader, it generates a **new unique** ID everytime - this is not the case with the Nokia phones or the MiFare cars.

I have install just about every NFC app on the market place (Play Store) - but still can't get any info to display on my PC through *any demo* app.

Could anyone please assist me in this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The randomized unique ID is a feature, not a bug. It helps keep your privacy. The fare collection systems should not rely on the unique ID, but on some other form of authentication with a crypto challenge.

Card emulation apps are not just like any other app, they require to run some code in a secure element (embedded on in the SIM). You can learn more about it by googling IzyNFC.